# Fitting to a piecewise function using Python

Tags: python, numpy

I'm trying to fit a piecewise function with absolute values using Numpy.

The mathematical function is

x < p[1]: y = 1 + p[0] * abs((size + x - p[1]) / size - size / 2)

x >= p[1]: y = 1 + p[0] * abs((x - p[1]) / size - size / 2)

Here's my Python function:

```
fitfunc = lambda p, x: \
    x < p[1] and\
    1 + p[0] * abs((data['n1'].size + x - p[1]) / data['n1'].size - data['n1'].size / 2) or\
    1 + p[0] * abs((x - p[1]) / data['n1'].size - data['n1'].size / 2)
```

Though, I'm getting the error:

```
The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()
```

However, any and all evaluate an entire list to a single boolean value.

More info:

I've used lambdas to fit data to a sine wave by using the following:

```
fitfunc = lambda p, x: 1 + p[0] * sin(pi * x / data['n1'].size + p[1])
errfunc = lambda p, x, y: fitfunc(p, x) - y # Distance to the target function
```

Then in a loop:

```
data = np.genfromtxt(dataFileName, names=('n1', 'n2'))
xAxisSeries = scipy.linspace(0., data['n1'].max(), data['n1'].size)

p0 = [489., 123.] # Initial guess for the parameters
p1, success = scipy.optimize.leastsq(errfunc, p0[:], args=(xAxisSeries, data['n2']))

#time says which points from the sine wave will be plotted
time = scipy.linspace(0., data['n1'].max(), 100)
pylab.plot(time, fitfunc(p1, time), 'r-')
```

I'm trying to use a lambda function because optimize.leastsq requires one. I'm using the exact same code with the exception of fitfunc being changed.

Comment: When do you get this error? How do you invoke this function? What do you pass to it?

Comment: There's a misconception here.  Functions constructed with def are perfectly good inputs to other functions.  The reason for lambda in Python is to create anonymous functions, but given that you are naming them, there's no point to avoiding def.

Answer (score 2):

The code above does not look idiomatic and is making life harder than it should be.  :)

If you're trying to define a function and give it a name at the same time, the conventional approach is to use *def*, not *lambda*.

```
fitfunc = lambda p, x: ...  ## you're making a named function, so just do...

def fitfunc(p, x): ...
```

And once you have that, you don't have to simulate short-circuiting branches with 'and' and 'or': you can just use *if*.  You're getting into trouble trying to simulate *if*.

Answer (score 0):

Truely speaking, it is not clear what you are trying to do with your lambda function.
But maybe it is the time of the day on my side of the globe...

In anycase, do note, that any(somelist) and np.array().any() are the same, but can be called differently.

```
In [2]: a=np.ones(4)

In [3]: a
Out[3]: array([ 1.,  1.,  1.,  1.])
In [4]: a.any()
Out[4]: True

In [8]: a[1]=0

In [9]: a.all()
Out[9]: False

In [11]: somelist=["1","1","a","3"]

In [12]: any(somelist)
Out[12]: True
```

Do note also comment, how do you call this function? Can you please post more code?

Answer (score 0):

Use def and scipy.optimize.curve_fit().

```
import scipy.optimize as so

def fitfunc(p, x):
    '''Define fit function'''
    if x < p[1]:
        return 1 + p[0] * abs((data['n1'].size + x - p[1]) / data['n1'].size - data['n1'].size / 2)
    else:
        return 1 + p[0] * abs((x - p[1]) / data['n1'].size - data['n1'].size / 2)

popt, pcov = so.curve_fit(fitfunc, x, y)
```

Comment: I have now created a function that looks like that. But, popt returns as [1.] and pcov returns as inf. I saw there's a p0 guess parameter for curve_fit but trying to put my own guess parameters in that gives the error:

    TypeError: fitfunc() takes exactly 2 arguments (3 given)

I'm calling it as:

    p1, success = optimize.curve_fit(fitfunc, xAxisSeries, data['n2'], p0=p0)